# p:watermark clears on updating Component even if there is no value

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces `p:watermark` on a `p:inputText`. Its working fine.
When ever I update the component its loosing watermark,even when there is no content inside the `p:inputText`

```
<h:form id="reg_frm">
   <p:inputText id="name" value="#{user.name}"/>
   <p:watermark value="your name" for="name" id="name_watermark" />

   <p:selectOneMenu value="#{user.drpvalue}">
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="One" itemValue="1"/>
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="two" itemValue="2"/>
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="three" itemValue="3"/>
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="four" itemValue="4"/>
      <p:ajax event="change" update="name name_watermark"/>
   </p:selectOneMenu>

</h:form>
```

> How do I retain the Watermark when there is no content in the
>   `p:inputText` after update?

*Note: Primefaces version - 3.5*

Comment: Have you tried setting an id to the `watermark` (for example `name_watermark`) and updating both components? `update="name name_watermark"` Or just update the whole `@form` if you can.

Comment: @XtremeBiker : As a mater of fact its an AJAX update,(please see the changed code in question now). Its working when i Update entire form, but I don't want that.

Comment: Neither when updating only that two elements?

Comment: Put a panelgroup around the two components and update that one. It should have the same effect like rendering the whole form.

Comment: @XtremeBiker : Yes It didn't work when I update both the components.

Comment: @noone : It worked well. Thanks Very much. why don't you put that as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the PrimeFaces showcase for watermarks: "Watermark displays a hint about input fields by using native placeholder in supported browsers and a javascript solution in others browser compatibility."

PrimeFaces probably adds some hidden javascript stuff to the element which is a parent of both components (input and watermark). In your case that's the form which you would need to update. If you don't want that, put a new panelgroup around both elements and update that, which will have the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

Try this attribute:

```
oncomplete="PrimeFaces.showWatermarks()"
```

It was given in Primefaces User's Guide.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and pointing out from User's guide. But it didn't work. I didn't get it why? As its is clearly mentioned in User's guide to use this attribute for this purpose only.